# Will a commit be garbage collected if it's referred to by tag but not by branch?

Tags: git, tags, branch, commit

I've got an annotated tag referring to a commit (does it matter if it is annotated?) and no branch referring there. Will the commit be garbage collected after some time?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, the commit will not be garbage collected. A reference from a tag is sufficient to keep a commit alive.

Comment: The git-gc documentation at http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html mentions this under the Notes section. "it will keep not only objects referenced by your current set of branches and tags..."

Answer (score 15):

tags and branches are both **refs**, if a ref is pointing to a commit, it's not garbage collected. You can also have custom refs, but those are uncommon.