# git - Is it safe to delete a branch which has a tag based on a merge commit?

Tags: git, merge, tags, branch

Let's say that I peform a non-fast-forward merge from branch `a` to branch `b`. This means that `b` is now 1 commit ahead of `a` i.e. the merge commit. I then tag this merge commit. Then I delete branch `b`.

Why is it that my tag is still available? Will it disappear at some point in the future via garbage collection?

Comment: I've just noticed a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055877/will-a-commit-be-garbage-collected-if-its-referred-to-by-tag-but-not-by-branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Why is it that my tag is still available?"**

Tags don't need to be referenced by a branch to be kept around.

**"Will it disappear at some point in the future via garbage collection?"**

No, the tag is a permanent reference and any commit reachable through the tag will also be kept from garbage collection.

This is one of the main features of a tag.